# When we must update version inside the composer.json file, when using the git flow

Tags: php, git, composer-php, git-flow

I am trying to implement the git flow, inside a php project. I am adding a new feature. The last tag is 1.1.0.

Now, I am not in a 1.1.0 version (because I am adding a new feature). This means that I must not update version inside the composer.json file.

Should I update version, when a feature is added to develop? Lice 1.1-feature-name?

Should I update version, only inside the release branch? I think the right moment is the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Symfony on Github. At time of writing, the `master` branch uses: `3.0-dev`.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/composer.json

Now look at tag `2.7.6`. That uses: `2.7-dev`.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.7.6/composer.json

Finally, if you look at all of the listed branches, you will notice they are named after each "major.minor" version.

The pattern they are using, is to add all new feature to the master branch, which is always the "next" version of the code.  So you will be adding this feature to a "feature branch", it really doesn't matter what you call it at this stage, but your composer file will say:

```
"dev-master": "1.2-dev"
```

When your feature is complete, you will merge that into "master", which should already have the "1.2.0" prepared in the composer file.

Now, when you are ready to release 1.2, you will tag it as `1.2.0`, followed by creating the branch "1.2", and committing.

Finally, you will change the composer file on "master" to "1.3-dev" and commit.  All new features after this will target "1.3.0".

**Post release**

You will need to maintain 1.2, so your patches will be applied to the 1.2 branch.  However, you will want these patches applied to master as well, so on master you use `git merge 1.2`.  So you are still adding features to master, but pulling patches from a previous version at the same time.

Comment: So, ... "major.minor" branches are always named "major.minor-dev" in composer.json and simply, ... when a version is ready, the branch is tagged major.minor.X. Again, if I have 4.5.42 version, composer.json says 4.5-dev in 4.5 branch, but also 4.6-dev in master branch. Is it right?

Comment: But, ... if I have the fix 2.3.31, I need to merge 2.3 in all other branches from 2.4 to master? Or only master?

Comment: @sensorario Thats right, but if a bug is found in 2.3, the general rule is to fix it in the lowest supported minor version, then merge it with each version branch up to master.  Its a little hard to explain since everyone kinda has their own formula, but I find Symfony2 has the most coherent practice.  The branches will be called "major.minor" (2.3), the composer will say "major.minor-dev" (2.3-dev), the tag will say "major.minor.patch" (2.3.1).  Ah, there was a mistake in my answer, I changed it to `"dev-master": "1.2-dev"`.